# Modifying script to capture login/shutdown times in Windows

Tags: windows-7, script, logging, event-log, event-viewer

For some time now I've been using this script to view my login time for a particular computer:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Windows\setupact.log")
Wscript.Echo "Log on today at " & FormatDateTime(objFile.DateLastModified,vbShortTime)
```

This is a Windows 7 Enterprise edition computer with Service Pack 1 installed. It is connected to a domain, and I am unable to change group policy.

Is it possible to modify the script to capture both the login and shutdown time? And, if so, is it possible to capture this for a set period (e.g. for the previous week or the previous 28 days)? The script doesn't necessarily have to store/save this info - I can live with just being able to view it.

I also came across this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/337371/how-can-i-use-event-viewer-to-confirm-login-times-filtered-by-user), but this didn't help me much (beyond the fact that it opened my eyes to Event Viewer.

I have since discovered I can manually view the information I need by viewing various logs in Event Viewer, but I'm not sure if there is some way to leverage off this information in a script or not. Obviously this information must be 'stored' somewhere on the system, but I'm not entirely sure where and whether it's accessible.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is this computer joined to a domain?  If yes,  can you modify group policy?

Comment: Yes it is, and no, I can't modify group policy. I'll update my question to mention these facts.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a script that might suit your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, colEvents, objEvent
Dim dtmStart, dtmEnd, strUser

strComputer = "West204"
dtmStart = "20091228000000.000000-360"
dtmEnd = "20100101000000.000000-360"
strUser = "MyDomain\jsmith"
strUser = "jsmith"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=Pkt,(Security)}!\\" _ 
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Security' AND " _
        & "TimeWritten >= '" & dtmStart & "' AND TimeWritten < '" _
        & dtmEnd & "' AND " _
        & "(EventCode = '528' OR EventCode = '540' OR EventCode = '538')")

For Each objEvent In colEvents
    Wscript.Echo "---------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Computer: " & objEvent.ComputerName
    Wscript.Echo "Event Code: " & objEvent.EventCode
    Wscript.Echo "Message: " & objEvent.Message
    Wscript.Echo "Time: " & objEvent.TimeWritten
    Wscript.Echo "Event Type: " & objEvent.EventType
    Wscript.Echo "User: " & objEvent.User
Next
```

Just replace the `strComputer`, `dtmStart`, `dtmEnd`, `strUser` and `strUser` with your information.

> These queries are always slow. I tried to add a WHERE clause for the
>   user, but could not get it to work, so the output will include all
>   logon/logoff events between the dates. I also expected more WHERE
>   clauses to make the query faster, but it doesn't seem to work that
>   way. Run the script at a command prompt and redirect the output to a
>   text file. The date format is yyyymmddhhmmss.ssssss-zzz, were -zzz is
>   your local time zone bias in minutes (from UTC)

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/db593fb8-e75b-4704-96c3-fef95ac03766/need-to-find-user-account-login-dates-and-times?forum=winservergen)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Or I just can't get it to work. I do get it to run, but the output is always the same: _Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved._ That is, there's nothing more after that.